# How to enable anti-alias for small fonts in QGraphicsView under Windows

Tags: qt, antialiasing, qgraphicsview

I have tried pass QPainter::Antialiasing to QGraphicsView::setRenderHints, and pass QFont::PreferAntialias to QFont::setStyleStrategy, but in vain. Small fonts can not be rendered anti-alias in QGraphicsView under Windows.

Comment: what do you mean by 'small'? If what you are rendering is only a few pixels in size anti aliasing will not help much. There's not enough resolution in the device to render it